# Freeform Pro checkbox group displaying checkbox above label

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm having a problem with checkboxes displaying above their label when using `{freeform:field:FIELD_NAME}` for checkbox_group field types.

I've tried applying classes by using `attr:NAME` as well as wrapper_open/close and row_wrapper_open/close options, but nothing is working.

Is there some way to make my checkboxes display inline with their labels that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like all you need to do is apply `display: inline;` to both your `label` and `input` elements. Those elements are `inline` by default, so is it possible that you're setting them to `block` somewhere else in your stylesheet? Also, check your markup output in Developer Tools or Firebug; are your `label` and `input` wrapped in a block-level element?

For me, I did something like this:

```
{if composer:field_type == 'checkbox_group'}
    {freeform:field:{composer:field_name}
        attr:class="control--checkbox-group"
        wrapper_open="<div>"
        wrapper_close="</div>"
        row_wrapper_open="<div>"
        row_wrapper_close="</div>"
        input_wrapper_open=""
        input_wrapper_close=""
    }
{/if}
```

The markup looks like this: http://cl.ly/image/1w1o1f1P1X2N; and then I used the class `control--checkbox-group` to style and format the controls.